# Return model and relations newly inserted

Tags: bluebird, bookshelf.js

I have a model named Category and another one named Product.
There is a relation between the two models as is :

```
// Category Model
var Category = bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName : 'categories',
    hasTimestamps : true,
    products : function () {
        return this.hasMany(Product, 'category_id');
    }
});

// Product model
var Product = bookshelf.Model.extend({

    tableName : 'products',

    hasTimestamps : true,

    category : function() {
        return this.belongsTo(Category, 'category_id');
    }
});
```

I tried to insert one category alongside with 3 products following the example given the [documentation](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Bookshelf-instance-transaction) through a transaction. The insertion worked fine but I can't return all data inserted including the products (It's OK for the category but I get nothing for the newly products).

That is my full code :

```
bookshelf.transaction(function(t){


    var products = req.body.products;
    var tableProd = [];


    //if (!req.params.idCategory || req.params.idCategory ==0) {
        return Category.forge({
                            name : req.body.name,
                            code : req.body.code,
                            tax_percentage : req.body.tax_percentage,
                            description  : req.body.description 
                            })
                            .save(null, {transacting : t})
                            .tap(function (category) {


                            for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++){

                            tableProd.push({
                                            barcode : products[i].barcode,
                                            cip : products[i].cip,
                                            category_id : category.id,
                                            quantity : products[i].quantity,
                                            retail_price : products[i].retail_price,
                                            description : products[i].description,
                                            name : products[i].name,
                                            DCI_name : products[i].DCI_name,
                                            kind : products[i].kind,
                                            comment : products[i].comment,
                                            status : products[i].status,
                                            critical_threshold : products[i].critical_threshold,
                                            max_threshold : products[i].max_threshold,
                                            date_end : products[i].date_end
                                            });
                                }

                                return Promise.map(tableProd, function (info) {
                                    Product.forge(info).save(null, {transacting : t})
                                })


                    });
                })
                .then(function (category) {
                    var result = category.related('products').pluck('category_id');
                    console.log('Category' +  JSON.stringify(category.toJSON()) + ' resultat: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                    res.json({error : false, data : {category : category.toJSON()}})
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    console.log('Error msg : ' + err.message);
                })
```

What is wrong with this statement : 
`category.related('products').pluck('category_id')`

How can I get all the data inserted : the category including the 3 products ?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me;

```
var ADDRESS = bookshelf.Model.extend({
tableName: 'ADDRESSES'});

var ADDRESSES = bookshelf.Collection.extend({
model: ADDRESS});

var addressArray = new Array();
for(var i=0; i<datas.length; i++) {
    addressArray.push({
        field1: datas[i].field1,
        ...
    });
}
var addressCollection = ADDRESSES.forge(addressArray);
addressCollection.invokeThen('save').then(function(addressResults) {
      console.log(addressResults);
});
```

You can loop over the addressResults and extract inserted id. Have fun :)